# How to extract numbers between multiple underscores

Tags: r, regex

I have files as following:

```
"C:/FolderInf/infoAnalysis/und_2017_01_28_12.csv"
```

And I would like to extract the figures (actually a date) from the file names using `gsub()`, `sub()` basically without any package involved.

Number of failed trials:

`gsub("\\D", "", lfs)` here also the last give `12` appears, I need only the first 8 figures!

`gsub("(.+?)(\\_.*)", "\\2", lfs)` complication in removing the rest unwanted characters....

Comment: Do they all follow the same general pattern? Can there be numbers in other places?

Comment: yes, they follow the same patern, however the last numbers after last underscore could be of different lenght...1, or 12, 123, 1234 etc.

Comment: what do you mean by extract date? Do you want it to be separate day month year etc in separate strings? write your output the way you expect and write down the class of each of the objects that you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `basename` to extract part of the string and then match one or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by a `_` or `|` a `_` followed by one or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with a blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^_]+_|_[^_]+$", "", basename(str1))
#[1] "2017_01_28"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "C:/FolderInf/infoAnalysis/und_2017_01_28_12.csv"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify this extraction exactly:

```
gsub(".*(\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "2017_01_28"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try (but there's probably more elegant solutions available):

```
substr(gsub("[^0-9]","",test),1,8)


[1] "20170128"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using R base function strsplit (No package needed)

```
paste(as.character(unlist(strsplit(as.character(string),"[_.]"))[c(2,3,4)]),collapse=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have told they are dates, you can use the next regexp, for example:

```
^[^_]*_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RYdcQm/2>.).  Beware that you cannot abbreviate this expression as `_([0-9]*){4}`, as you would end with only a matching group (and not the four that the above expression has) and wouldn't get the four numbers.  If you need only the date, you can cut the regexp before the last group.